# Generic search form/panel in Wicket

Tags: search, wicket, panel, dao

I am trying to implement a generic search form/panel in Wicket. The form should allow searches in several fields in an Entity (using the DAO pattern) in order to filter the output of a ListView or a DataView. What is the best way to do this? I've thought of doing this using an extended DataProvider but I haven't really seen any real example.

Did anyone implemented such a thing? Some pointers would be nice.

**edit**

An aditional question that might help set the direction of the answers:

- Do Wicket Models combine well with DataProviders?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can extend IDataProvider with search methods:

```
    public interface SearchableDataProvider<T> extends IDataProvider<T> {

    public void setSearchQuery(String... query);

    public void clearSearchQuery();


    @Override
    public Iterator<? extends T> iterator(int first, int count);


    @Override
    public int size();

}
```

And implement this interface in your EntityManagers such as UserManager, ArticleManager or AccountManager.

Comment: This would be a good way to implement it - except I already have my DAOs implemented, so building my own "String ... query" would not be feasible. I am trying to implement something more turned to wicket models... but I'm not really sure they (wicket models) combine well with a DataProvider

Comment: Actually this answer helped me find a way on how to do this - so i'll accept it. Basically I will bind several Models to several TextFields and apply the onchange behaviour and reset the provider output... much like the answer given but with models instead of queries. Thanks.